# boost::asio::ssl linking errors in Xcode 4

Tags: c++, xcode4, compiler-errors, openssl, boost-asio

I have a simple project in Xcode—it doesn't actually do anything yet, just includes `boost::asio::ssl`:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

using namespace std ;

int main (int argc, const char * argv [] ) {
    return 0 ;
}
```

I have it linked with `libssl.dylib` and `libboost_system.dylib`, and get this when building:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CONF_modules_unload", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init() in main.o
  "_CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init() in main.o
  "_CRYPTO_num_locks", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init() in main.o
  "_CRYPTO_set_id_callback", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init() in main.o
      boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init() in main.o
  "_CRYPTO_set_locking_callback", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init() in main.o
      boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init() in main.o
  "_ENGINE_cleanup", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init() in main.o
  "_ERR_free_strings", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init() in main.o
  "_ERR_reason_error_string", referenced from:
      boost::asio::error::detail::ssl_category::message(int) const in main.o
  "_ERR_remove_state", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init() in main.o
  "_EVP_cleanup", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::~do_init() in main.o
  "_OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::detail::openssl_init_base::do_init::do_init() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there some other library I'm missing or something else I've overlooked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to link against libcrypto as well `-lcrypto`

Comment: Thanks, linking with libcrypto seems to have done it. For me (Xcode, remember) this meant adding `libcrypto.dylib` to the list of libraries to link against (click on the project in the left sidebar, *Build Phases* tab, *Link Binary With Libraries*); for users building with the command-line tools it would mean adding `-lcrypto` to the command line.